# Is 240V to 24V DC PSU to 120V 60Hz inverter a low cost way to convert 240V 50Hz to 120V 60Hz?

Tags: power-supply, voltage, frequency, inverter, conversion

I've been looking at the companies providing step down frequency changing units in the 2000W range, and their enormous size seems to be reflected in an equally enormous price. SO...why can't I just use a 240V 50Hz to (say) 24V DC switching power supply and connect the output to an (equally cheap) 2000W DC inverter to give 120V 60Hz? Seems too obvious to be viable...any thoughts, or anyone tried this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide links to the typical parts you have looked at so that someone can refute your claims or substantiate them with reasons.

Comment: I wonder why you need 60Hz. Vintage computer or video equipment?

Answer (score 1):

What you say will work, but will be inefficient and not "cheap" at those power levels.

24 V is not a great choice of intermediate DC voltage since the current will need to be quite high.  Do the math.  (2 kW)/(24 V) = 83 A, and that's not even accounting for the inefficiency of the inverter.  Higher voltages allow for lower current, which should help with both price and peformance.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to rectify 240V/50Hz and then use a frequency inverter to obtain 120VAC/60Hz.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7KDp1.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>